# CMake Error ...: DNN: CUDA backend requires CUDA Toolkit. Please resolve dependency or disable OPENCV_DNN_CUDA=OFF

Tags: opencv, cmake, ubuntu-20.04

Here is the error I am getting when I am compiling OpenCV on ubuntu 20.04 with cuda 10.1.

```
-- Detected processor: x86_64
CMake Warning at cmake/OpenCVUtils.cmake:721 (message):
  Unexpected option: WITH_CUBLAS (=ON)

  Condition: IF (WITH_CUDA)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:249 (OCV_OPTION)


CMake Warning at cmake/OpenCVUtils.cmake:721 (message):
  Unexpected option: WITH_CUDNN (=ON)

  Condition: IF (WITH_CUDA)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:252 (OCV_OPTION)


-- Looking for ccache - not found
-- Found ZLIB: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so (found suitable version "1.2.11", minimum required is "1.2.3") 
-- Could NOT find OpenJPEG (minimal suitable version: 2.0, recommended version >= 2.3.1)
-- Could NOT find Jasper (missing: JASPER_LIBRARIES JASPER_INCLUDE_DIR) 
-- Found ZLIB: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so (found version "1.2.11") 
-- Found OpenEXR: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libIlmImf.so
-- found Intel IPP (ICV version): 2020.0.0 [2020.0.0 Gold]
-- at: /home/murat/opencv/build/3rdparty/ippicv/ippicv_lnx/icv
-- found Intel IPP Integration Wrappers sources: 2020.0.0
-- at: /home/murat/opencv/build/3rdparty/ippicv/ippicv_lnx/iw
-- Could not find OpenBLAS include. Turning OpenBLAS_FOUND off
-- Could not find OpenBLAS lib. Turning OpenBLAS_FOUND off
-- Could NOT find Atlas (missing: Atlas_CLAPACK_INCLUDE_DIR) 
-- A library with LAPACK API found.
-- OpenCV Python: during development append to PYTHONPATH: /home/murat/opencv/build/python_loader
-- Caffe:   NO
-- Protobuf:   NO
-- Glog:   YES
-- freetype2:   YES (ver 23.1.17)
-- harfbuzz:    YES (ver 2.6.4)
-- HDF5: Using hdf5 compiler wrapper to determine C configuration
-- Julia not found. Not compiling Julia Bindings. 
-- Module opencv_ovis disabled because OGRE3D was not found
-- No preference for use of exported gflags CMake configuration set, and no hints for include/library directories provided. Defaulting to preferring an installed/exported gflags CMake configuration if available.
-- Found installed version of gflags: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/gflags
-- Detected gflags version: 2.2.2
-- Checking SFM deps... TRUE
-- CERES support is disabled. Ceres Solver for reconstruction API is required.
-- Checking for module 'tesseract'
--   No package 'tesseract' found
-- Tesseract:   NO
-- Allocator metrics storage type: 'long long'
-- HDF5: Using hdf5 compiler wrapper to determine C configuration
CMake Error at modules/dnn/CMakeLists.txt:35 (message):
  DNN: CUDA backend requires CUDA Toolkit.  Please resolve dependency or
  disable OPENCV_DNN_CUDA=OFF

-- Registering hook 'INIT_MODULE_SOURCES_opencv_dnn': /home/murat/opencv/modules/dnn/cmake/hooks/INIT_MODULE_SOURCES_opencv_dnn.cmake
-- opencv_dnn: filter out cuda4dnn source code
-- No preference for use of exported gflags CMake configuration set, and no hints for include/library directories provided. Defaulting to preferring an installed/exported gflags CMake configuration if available.
-- Found installed version of gflags: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/gflags
-- Detected gflags version: 2.2.2
-- Checking SFM deps... TRUE
-- CERES support is disabled. Ceres Solver for reconstruction API is required.
-- 
-- General configuration for OpenCV 4.4.0 =====================================
--   Version control:               unknown
-- 
--   Extra modules:
--     Location (extra):            /home/murat/opencv_contrib/modules
--     Version control (extra):     unknown
-- 
--   Platform:
--     Timestamp:                   2021-02-18T12:05:50Z
--     Host:                        Linux 5.8.0-43-generic x86_64
--     CMake:                       3.16.3
--     CMake generator:             Unix Makefiles
--     CMake build tool:            /usr/bin/make
--     Configuration:               RELEASE
-- 
--   CPU/HW features:
--     Baseline:                    SSE SSE2 SSE3
--       requested:                 SSE3
--     Dispatched code generation:  SSE4_1 SSE4_2 FP16 AVX AVX2 AVX512_SKX
--       requested:                 SSE4_1 SSE4_2 AVX FP16 AVX2 AVX512_SKX
--       SSE4_1 (15 files):         + SSSE3 SSE4_1
--       SSE4_2 (1 files):          + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2
--       FP16 (0 files):            + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 FP16 AVX
--       AVX (4 files):             + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 AVX
--       AVX2 (29 files):           + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 FP16 FMA3 AVX AVX2
--       AVX512_SKX (4 files):      + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 FP16 FMA3 AVX AVX2 AVX_512F AVX512_COMMON AVX512_SKX
-- 
--   C/C++:
--     Built as dynamic libs?:      YES
--     C++ standard:                11
--     C++ Compiler:                /usr/bin/c++  (ver 9.3.0)
--     C++ flags (Release):         -fsigned-char -ffast-math -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wuninitialized -Winit-self -Wsuggest-override -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-comment -Wimplicit-fallthrough=3 -Wno-strict-overflow -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections  -msse -msse2 -msse3 -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -O3 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG
--     C++ flags (Debug):           -fsigned-char -ffast-math -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wuninitialized -Winit-self -Wsuggest-override -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-comment -Wimplicit-fallthrough=3 -Wno-strict-overflow -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections  -msse -msse2 -msse3 -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -g  -O0 -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG
--     C Compiler:                  /usr/bin/cc
--     C flags (Release):           -fsigned-char -ffast-math -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wuninitialized -Winit-self -Wno-comment -Wimplicit-fallthrough=3 -Wno-strict-overflow -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections  -msse -msse2 -msse3 -fvisibility=hidden -O3 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG
--     C flags (Debug):             -fsigned-char -ffast-math -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wuninitialized -Winit-self -Wno-comment -Wimplicit-fallthrough=3 -Wno-strict-overflow -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections  -msse -msse2 -msse3 -fvisibility=hidden -g  -O0 -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG
--     Linker flags (Release):      -Wl,--exclude-libs,libippicv.a -Wl,--exclude-libs,libippiw.a   -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,--as-needed  
--     Linker flags (Debug):        -Wl,--exclude-libs,libippicv.a -Wl,--exclude-libs,libippiw.a   -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,--as-needed  
--     ccache:                      NO
--     Precompiled headers:         NO
--     Extra dependencies:          dl m pthread rt
--     3rdparty dependencies:
-- 
--   OpenCV modules:
--     To be built:                 alphamat aruco bgsegm bioinspired calib3d ccalib core datasets dnn dnn_objdetect dnn_superres dpm face features2d flann freetype fuzzy gapi hdf hfs highgui img_hash imgcodecs imgproc intensity_transform line_descriptor ml objdetect optflow phase_unwrapping photo plot python3 quality rapid reg rgbd saliency sfm shape stereo stitching structured_light superres surface_matching text tracking ts video videoio videostab xfeatures2d ximgproc xobjdetect xphoto
--     Disabled:                    world
--     Disabled by dependency:      -
--     Unavailable:                 cnn_3dobj cudaarithm cudabgsegm cudacodec cudafeatures2d cudafilters cudaimgproc cudalegacy cudaobjdetect cudaoptflow cudastereo cudawarping cudev cvv java js julia matlab ovis python2 viz
--     Applications:                perf_tests apps
--     Documentation:               NO
--     Non-free algorithms:         YES
-- 
--   GUI: 
--     GTK+:                        YES (ver 3.24.20)
--       GThread :                  YES (ver 2.64.6)
--       GtkGlExt:                  NO
--     OpenGL support:              NO
-- 
--   Media I/O: 
--     ZLib:                        /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so (ver 1.2.11)
--     JPEG:                        /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so (ver 80)
--     WEBP:                        build (ver encoder: 0x020f)
--     PNG:                         /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng.so (ver 1.6.37)
--     TIFF:                        build (ver 42 - 4.0.10)
--     JPEG 2000:                   build Jasper (ver 1.900.1)
--     OpenEXR:                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libImath.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libIlmImf.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libIex.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libHalf.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libIlmThread.so (ver 2_3)
--     HDR:                         YES
--     SUNRASTER:                   YES
--     PXM:                         YES
--     PFM:                         YES
-- 
--   Video I/O:
--     DC1394:                      YES (2.2.5)
--     FFMPEG:                      YES
--       avcodec:                   YES (58.54.100)
--       avformat:                  YES (58.29.100)
--       avutil:                    YES (56.31.100)
--       swscale:                   YES (5.5.100)
--       avresample:                YES (4.0.0)
--     GStreamer:                   YES (1.16.2)
--     v4l/v4l2:                    YES (linux/videodev2.h)
-- 
--   Parallel framework:            TBB (ver 2020.2 interface 11102)
-- 
--   Trace:                         YES (with Intel ITT)
-- 
--   Other third-party libraries:
--     Intel IPP:                   2020.0.0 Gold [2020.0.0]
--            at:                   /home/murat/opencv/build/3rdparty/ippicv/ippicv_lnx/icv
--     Intel IPP IW:                sources (2020.0.0)
--               at:                /home/murat/opencv/build/3rdparty/ippicv/ippicv_lnx/iw
--     Lapack:                      NO
--     Eigen:                       YES (ver 3.3.7)
--     Custom HAL:                  NO
--     Protobuf:                    build (3.5.1)
-- 
--   cuDNN:                         NO
-- 
--   OpenCL:                        YES (no extra features)
--     Include path:                /home/murat/opencv/3rdparty/include/opencl/1.2
--     Link libraries:              Dynamic load
-- 
--   Python 3:
--     Interpreter:                 /usr/bin/python3 (ver 3.8.5)
--     Libraries:                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.8.so (ver 3.8.5)
--     numpy:                       /home/murat/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/include (ver 1.18.5)
--     install path:                lib/python3.8/dist-packages/cv2/python-3.8
-- 
--   Python (for build):            /usr/bin/python3
-- 
--   Java:                          
--     ant:                         NO
--     JNI:                         /usr/lib/jvm/default-java/include /usr/lib/jvm/default-java/include/linux /usr/lib/jvm/default-java/include
--     Java wrappers:               NO
--     Java tests:                  NO
-- 
--   Install to:                    /usr/local
-- -----------------------------------------------------------------
-- 
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/murat/opencv/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/murat/opencv/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

Here are my cmake flags:

```
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE 
-D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local 
-D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=~/opencv_contrib/modules 
-D BUILD_TIFF=ON 
-D WITH_FFMPEG=ON 
-D WITH_GSTREAMER=ON 
-D WITH_TBB=ON 
-D BUILD_TBB=ON 
-D WITH_EIGEN=ON 
-D WITH_V4L=ON 
-D WITH_LIBV4L=ON 
-D WITH_VTK=OFF 
-D WITH_QT=OFF 
-D WITH_OPENGL=ON 
-D OPENCV_ENABLE_NONFREE=ON 
-D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=OFF 
-D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=OFF 
-D BUILD_NEW_PYTHON_SUPPORT=ON 
-D OPENCV_GENERATE_PKGCONFIG=ON 
-D BUILD_TESTS=OFF

-D OPENCV_DNN_CUDA=ON 
-D ENABLE_FAST_MATH=ON 
-D CUDA_FAST_MATH=ON 
-D CUDA_ARCH_BIN=7.0 
-D WITH_CUBLAS=ON 
-D WITH_CUDNN=ON 
-D CUDNN_LIBRARY=/usr/lib/cuda/lib64/libcudnn.so.7.6.5 
-D CUDNN_INCLUDE_DIR=/usr/lib/cuda/include 
-D BUILD_EXAMPLES=OFF 
-D PYTHON_DEFAULT_EXECUTABLE=$(which python3) ..
```

It works perfectly with the option `-D OPENCV_DNN_CUDA=OFF`. But I need CUDA libraries. My CUDA and CUDNN paths are correct, so I have no idea what is wrong with the cmake compilation. Did anyone face with a similar problem when installing opencv?

Note: I am following this [link](https://qengineering.eu/install-caffe-on-ubuntu-20.04-with-opencv-4.4.html) to finally install caffe.

```
$ nvcc -V
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2019 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Sun_Jul_28_19:07:16_PDT_2019
Cuda compilation tools, release 10.1, V10.1.243
```

Answer (score 3):

(Version OpenCV 4.5.3.)  The OpenCV "DNN" module's cmake file opencv/modules/dnn/CMakeLists.txt is checking variable HAVE_CUDA, but this variable appears to never be set by a Performing Test by the time the DNN module is examined.  Worse, at the beginning there's also a

```
CMake Warning at cmake/OpenCVUtils.cmake:758 (message):
Unexpected option: WITH_CUDNN (=ON)
```

message. CUDNN_FOUND appears to be set, but not finding HAVE_CUDA. Perhaps a name got changed.

The twelfth-hour night-before-demo workaround is to remove the dnn folder from the opencv/modules directory.  This wipes out usage of downstream modules: barcode; dnn_objdetect; dnn_superres; mcc; text; and wechat_qrcode, but the system cmakes.

Specifying `-D CUDA_TOOLKIT_ROOT_DIR=/usr/local/cuda-11.4` may help but did not fix it. Note the system adds on /bin or also /bin64 to this internally, in order to verify the toolkit location based on `nvcc` or `nvcc.exe` at some point.

`libcudnn.so` is at the specified place, and does not seem to be the problem.

Comment: Thank you @DragonLord, the +100 reputation is well-earned. I'll take a look at this tonight and build it as you've prescribed.

Comment: issue somehow similar there while compiling on windows, opencv 4.6:, cudnn.lib copied from 7.5 build, but _OpenCV Could NOT find CUDNN: Found unsuitable version "..21", but required is at least "7.5" (found C:/Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit/CUDA/v11.7/lib/x64/cudnn.lib)_

Answer (score 0):

While things could be going wrong in a couple different directions, I believe there could be a flaw with the `.deb` archive file. It doesn't prepare a `libcudnn.so` where the OpenCV installation checks.

Because of this, I think it's necessary to use the generic Linux tarball installation. (https://developer.nvidia.com/compute/machine-learning/cudnn/secure/7.6.5.32/Production/10.2_20191118/cudnn-10.2-linux-x64-v7.6.5.32.tgz)